# Write DataFrame to Hive using pyodbc DSN connection

Tags: python, pandas, hive, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

How to write dataframe to hive table using pyodc connection. When written it gives programming error.. any other way to write data to hive from local.

error

```
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in execute(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1430             else:
-> 1431                 cur.execute(*args)
   1432             return cur

Error: ('HY000', "[HY000] [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (110) Error while executing a query in Impala: [HY000] : ParseException: Syntax error in line 1:\n...ERE type='table' AND name=?;\n                             ^\nEncountered: Unexpected character\nExpected: CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, LEFT, NOT, NULL, REPLACE, RIGHT, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER\n\nCAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error\n (110) (SQLPrepare)")
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
DatabaseError                             Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-8-9f82c88c3a27> in <module>
      1 import pyodbc
      2 with pyodbc.connect("DSN=*****", autocommit=True) as conn:
----> 3     df.to_sql(name='Xyz', con=conn, schema='fgh',if_exists='append',index=False)
```

Comment: hi, please display your error here so that it is easier for others to answer :)

Comment: updated the question with  error

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a raw  (DBAPI) `pyodbc.Connection` to pandas' `to_sql`. As the [documentation for to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) states, such a `Connection` object is assumed to be a sqlite3 connection, so `to_sql` is sending the query

```sql
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;
```

to interrogate the database. That won't work with Hive (or any database other than SQLite).

For any other database you need to pass `to_sql` a SQLAlchemy `Engine` or `Connection` object as the `con=` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I used this source for writing df into Hive:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/data-exploration/python-dataframe-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Assuming you have df with two columns, you can use the below code:
You need to make sure that your table exist in the database.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    writing_query = """
        INSERT INTO 
            table_name
        VALUES ('{}','{}')
        """ .format(row[0], row[1])

    conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=*****", autocommit=True) # Creates a connection with the database
    cursor = conn.cursor()  # Creates a cursor
    cursor.execute(writing_query) # Asks the cursor to execute the query
    conn.close() # Closes the connection
```